# Java Generics Question

Tags: java, generics

I following definitions of the class.

```
public class Test2<T extends Test3> {

     private T t ;


     public T foo() {
         Test3 test3 = new Test3();
         t = test3;  // I get compilation error here.**
         return t;
     }

}

class Test3 {

}
```

I get compilation error at line t=test3, saying "Type mismatch can not convert from Test3 to T;
What is wrong?

Comment: Can a child object variable refer to a parent object?

Comment: @Hovercraft: no, it cannot, that's precisely the problem (see my answer)

Comment: I know that Mark, I wanted the OP to understand it, but I posted as a comment rather than an answer. :(

Comment: @Hovercraft - +1 to your answer below for trying to use the Socratic method of teaching here and getting answered by another poster. Made me laugh.

Answer (score 8):

What you're doing is equivalent to this:

```
Integer n = new Number();
```

and has nothing to do with generics  (note that `Integer extends Number`).  The compiler is indicating you cannot assign a parent type to an instance of a child type, the parent type may not implement all the child type's required methods.

In this case `T` is the child type of `Test3`, or `Test3` itself.  So here, you're trying to assign the parent class (`T`) to a variable that contains the child class (`Test3`) and it fails, just like the example above.

Answer (score 2):

`T` is a subclass of `Test3`. As such, unless it is exactly `Test3` the assignment will fail since subclasses can be assigned to variables of a superclass type but the reverse is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Can a child object variable refer to a parent object?

Just test it without the generics:

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        T t = new Test3();
    }
}

class T extends Test3 {
}

class Test3 {
}
```

edit: nevermind, I initially posted as a comment, then posted as an answer... but was too late! :)

Answer (score 0):

Because it is downcast. T can be any class derived from Test3, if you sure (but why you need T, use always Test3) you can use follow explicit casting:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
t = (T)test3;
```

Comment: I want to return instance of Test3. Is writing method without Generics is only solution?

Comment: will it look ugly if I cast like following.               @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
t = (T)test3;